# How to print multiple datas in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // flatlist data
        this.state = {
            data: [
                { key: "Skptricks", data: "one", name: "one" },
                { key: "Sumit" , data: "two" , name: "one"},
                { key: "Amit" , data: "three", name: "one"},
            ],
        }
    }

    // flat list
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                    /> 
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what exactly do you need to print ? Please refer the code. I'm printing the 'name' item of your array. If you want to print 'data' items , use item.data inside renderItem. Let me know if you need any help.

```
const DATA = [{ key: "Skptricks", data: "one", name: "one" },
{ key: "Sumit" , data: "two" , name: "one"},
{ key: "Amit" , data: "three", name: "one"},
];

const Item = ({ name }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item name={item.name} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```